# textures loading in eevee renders but not in cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

The textures I set up work fine when I try to render it in Eevee, but when I try to render the image in Cycles it just shows up as a black texture that doesn't take light.

This is what the image looks like in Eevee as well as the texture nodes:
[image]

And this is what the image looks like in Cycles:
[image]

This is the blend file:
[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks like there's a problem at the end of your node chain? Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Switch your preview mode to *Rendered*, you have no light in your scene, create a light.

[image]